# How to configure home router to act as middleman DNS server?

Tags: networking, router, dns

I want to accomplish few things for people in my local network with private local IP addresses.

1. If someone types www.mydomain.abc, it's used as alias to some mysubdomain.herokuapp.com
2. If someone types oursocialnetwork.local, they are taken to the internal server which is matched using MAC address (local IP addresses are dynamic)
3. If a request does not match any domains in list then it just goes the usual way.
4. Ideally do it without everyone having to define custom DNS server.
   (Can't the router see if DNS lookup request is being made and if for certain URL then return local IP, or IP for another site?)

So even though www.mydomain.abc doesn't exist officially in the real world, it does for everyone behind the router.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use either:

1) A custom DNS server (which you don't want to). Take note that this will probably increase the performance of the entire network, so if you can afford it, this is a great option.

2) A WINS server.

3) Some routers support this, but I can't say anything here.

Comment: for #1 is it possible to make router the dns server and have it intercept requests for dns lookup and then reroute to local

Comment: Depends on the router.  If it is linux-based and you can install+configure either dnsmasq/bind9, then you basically can do anything you need.